# Highcharts - yAxis labels are overlapping for multiple series data

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a highchart rendered for multiple series data. However the y axis labels are overlapping. Is there a way to fix it?

Here's the link: https://jsfiddle.net/sharadkalya/mhg52js4/

[image]

Answer (score -1):

In the demo you've included you have 6 y-axis defined. Some of them have the same *(min, max)* range. Naturally, the labels will cover each other if the position of the axis is not altered.

I do not know much about the purpose of your project, but it's very rare to have the need to define so many axes.

You do not need to define an additional axis to influence the labels value.

- You can simply use the `yAxis.labels.formatter` to format all the labels (https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.labels.formatter).
- You can also set `yAxis.tickPositions` to show the *ticks* only in certain positions (https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.tickPositions).
- You can set `yAxis.min` and `yAxis.max` to define a range covered by your axis (https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.min)

Here's a **demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/dpoL7r4h/

Comment: It's a common use case to have multiple axes graph. See https://www.highcharts.com/demo/highcharts/combo-multi-axes

Comment: Of course, but as you can see in the demo you've sent each axis serves a certain purpose - the series attached is different, the scale is completely different, the formatter is different, the styling is different, the position is different. In your case, none of these hold true.

Could you please explain why do you have the need for 6 yAxis in the same positions? You can always move them with the yAxis.left and yAxis.top properties so that they do not overlap (https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.left).

Comment: Okay, so in my case I get different series from the server, and I need to render those series. You are saying that I should not use multiple axes. Only single yAxis can render multiple series data with different labels on them. That's okay I can do that, but do you know how to do that and that if doing so will solve the problem?
Your answer to my question doesn't help at all. Glad you are trying to help, but you didn't help.

Comment: With "different labels on them"? Could you elaborate on that? Do you have any image that you could show me how you want your chart to look like? If you send it to me, I'll gladly recreate it with Highcharts. If you don't have any image, as I've mentioned before, you can use the formatter functions to have a fully custom function to render the labels. Same goes for axis labels and series labels. Here's the API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.series.dataLabels.formatter